# Check for parent directory access to a request(URL) using predefined functions

Tags: c#

Need to know how i can give a check for parent directory access.

case 1: Path = https://18.56.199.56/Project/Docs/../Hello.File.txt
case 2: Path = https://18.56.199.56/Project/Docs/Hello..File.txt

Using some check i need to find the parent directory access(like case 1) and not ".." in the file name(like case 2)

With the below code i am getting the expected output but i need some predefined methods like Uri.AbsoluteUri Properties to do the same job.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       if (Path.Contains("../")) {
          // do something
       }
    }
}
```

Requirement: Need some predefined methods like below to do this job. Using below code i am getting isFile as false.

var isFile = new Uri(Path).AbsoluteUri.Split('/').Contains("..");

Comment: Hi SreekuttanPV, Welcome to stackoverflow, can you please update your question with expected output, I am unable to understand what exactly you want. Do you want to check is file contains `..` if yes then you need `HelloFile.txt` in some variable

Comment: Yeah i am finding this hard to understand

Comment: I want to check for parent directory access

Comment: case 1: Path = https://18.56.199.56/fgh/sdfgh/../Hello.File.txt
case 2: Path = https://18.56.199.56/fgh/sdfgh/Hello..File.txt


if(Path.Contains("..") {
 return null;
}

The above path check is failing for case 2 in my case. I need to check for parent directory check for a request(URL)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar i am not checking the string in a file. I am getting a request(url) in a function. If the request contains parent directory access(/../) then i need to do some action.

Answer (score 3):

To check if the path contains `../` you can use `string.Contains()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8

```
filePath1 = filePath1.Replace("../", "")

// To skip ../ in the path we check in the first contains if it's in the path.
// The definition of || is OR  
// To skip ./ in the path we check it in the second part of the if statement.
// So in pseudo code it says:
// if filepath1 conatains ../ OR if filepath1 contains ./ return null 
if (filePath1.Contains("../") || filePath1.Contains("./"))
    return null;
```

Comment: In this case output is comming as 'https://18.56.199.56/fgh/sdfgh/././///HelloFile.txt". I if ".." is comming in url then i need to return null.

Comment: @mjwills, static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Path1 = "https://18.56.199.56/fgh/sdfgh/../Hello.File.txt";
            string Path2 = "https://18.56.199.56/fgh/sdfgh/Hello..File.txt";

            if (Path2.IndexOf("..") > -1)
            {
                int a = 1;
            }

        }

Comment: @SreekuttanPV the problem with your current code is you are only checking for double dot, which is not fully qualified path access unless paired with a slash which is what Slurf is doing

Comment: @SreekuttanPV I'm not sure what you want? I updated the awnser with the pseudocode what it does. If this is not what you're searching for, please update the question again and clearly explain what you want with some examples.

Comment: @StuiterSlurf sorry i missed the slash. Its working fine. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Can we do the same job using Uri.AbsolutePath Property or with any other predefined class ?

Comment: @SreekuttanPV the part of `../` is valid in Uri for what I know. Maybe that it's not an absolute path. You can see this in the documentation or better yet, create a test program and try it out :-)